# Purpose and duration of USDA animal inspection certificate for international travel

Tags: international-travel, pets

I am attempting to bring my pet overseas.  I have an appointment to get her checked by an accredited veterinarian.  Afterward, the USDA must certify the certificate (in writing; my destination country does not accept digital seals/signatures).

I am flying on a Monday.  My vet will send the certificate to the USDA electronically on Friday.  The USDA website says certificates must be signed by the USDA no more than two days before flight.  They have told my vet that since there's a weekend in between, it's ok that mine will have a three day delay.

I'm concerned that workers at the check-in desk (Turkish Airlines, Chicago) may be instructed to look for a two-day max gap between certification from USDA and flight.  But the real question is, who looks at this certificate, where, and why, and will I have any issue having it certified by the USDA three days out?

Comment: You *may* get a better response on [Pets.SE](https://pets.stackexchange.com) as there are many questions there about traveling internationally with animals

Comment: @PeterM Thank you